# Get attributes of main component Ionic 2 / 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I create and open my database Sqlite and save my object SQLiteObject in variable in my app.component.ts. So i need to recover this attributes in my custom ORM where is extends in other providers to describe title and field of my tables.

How can i recover this ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very vague. But when I see the word "recover", I think local storage. https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

Otherwise, save the data in a service then inject that service elsewhere.